# Why doesn't PHP auto html decode my POST?

Tags: php, post, decode

I'm using Zend Framework for a project. Why when I make POST request and get the params in my controller by `$this->_request->getParams()` it shows undecoded values? For example a string like `Speakers & keyboards` in my HTML form is retrieved as `Speakers &amp; keyboards` from getParams() within PHP.

Doesn't PHP autodecode every posted value?

Comment: You are entering `&` into a form and are receiving `&amp;` on the server? That's rather odd.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I received. It's odd yeah!

Comment: Is it a plain text input? Or a JavaScript WYSIWYG editor? Check what the browser actually sends using Firebug / Chrome debugger / Charles / etc.

Comment: How are you determining what the data is? Are you echoing it raw to the browser? Dumping it to an error log? Outputting it through a template function that expects text and outputs HTML?

Comment: Look for the `filter.default=` setting in your **php.ini**, if there really is some auto-escaping going on. Not sure about ZF, but it might well have something similar built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hi John, thanks for the hint! I think that's the problem really as I'm making an AJAX POST request and it takes data from the page HTML. So I better use something like urlDecode() before sending the request... What do you think?

The problem then, is that you are sending HTML and you want text.

When you grab the content from the page, get text instead of HTML. So don't use `innerHTML` or jQuery's `.html()`. Get a textNode and read its `data` property, or use jQuery's `.text()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no reason to do so.

Data is encoded for transport, and then decoded again. HTML isn't an encoding used for transport.

The only reason to expect to receive HTML is if HTML was sent, and if HTML is sent then (presumably) HTML is desired. Converting to text wouldn't often be a desired thing to happen next.

Comment: David please see deceze's comment. I think you've probably misunderstood my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PHP autodecodes the escaped content, not content which is in HTML entities.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the hint! I think that's the problem really as I'm making an AJAX POST request and it takes data from the page HTML. So I better use something like urlDecode() before sending the request... What do you think?

Comment: I think I might use html_entity_decode javascript analog from http://phpjs.com before sending the ajax request. What do you think - is this a workaround, maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Why not do it on the server?  This forces anyone using the API to conform -- server-side validation is generally better than client-side.

Otherwise, I think the problem lies somewhere in your AJAX library.  URIEncode shouldn't add any entity encoding to your content.

Comment: Yes I use html_entity_decode on the server, I got confused while commenting this sorry. Thanks for the help! I was just wondering if this all is some kind of a workaround that I'm doing .... I use jQuery anyway

Comment: I've never noticed jQuery doing that.  Might be smart to fire up an HTTP sniffer to determine if the problem is in the JavaScript or in the PHP.  I'm 98% certain it would be on the client side, but that's wrong often enough.  You can use Firebug's Net panel, Webkit's Network panel, or an external app like Fiddler (windows) or HTTPScoop (Mac) for this.

Comment: I have this html on my page "Speakers &amp; keyboards", when I send it in the `data` param of `$.ajax` jquery call it passes it just like that, without decoding the &amp; part. Maybe that's normal and I have to decode it on server side?